# Background location not tracking above android 11 device

Tags: java, android, kotlin

We cannot get latitude and longitude of location tracking.
Please review the below code for background location tracking for android device.
This same code is working in older android version. but the same code is not working for the latest android version 11. It returns `null` in android 11 device and above

```
private void fn_getlocation() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    isGPSEnable = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    isNetworkEnable = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    if (!isGPSEnable && !isNetworkEnable) {

    } else {

        if (isNetworkEnable) {

            location = null;
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
 

              
                    return;
                }
 
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, this);
          

            if (locationManager != null) {

                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                if (location != null) {
                   
                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    longitude = location.getLongitude();

                    fn_update(location);
                }
            }

        }
        if (checkLocationPermission()) {

            if (isGPSEnable) {

                location = null;
               
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return;
                }
                
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, this);
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                      
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        fn_update(location);
                    }
                }
            }
        }


    }

}
```

manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.location" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/location#change-details

Comment: show your manifest also

Answer (score 2):

From Android 11 onward, your app needs to request for the `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` permission.

See https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions#request-background-location

Comment: we already added background location permission

Comment: @yogesh you need to ask for the Foreground permission first, after it is granted then you need to display to the user why you need background permission, then ask for background permission